# Are laser sharks feasible?

Tags: technology, fauna, ocean, lasers

**idea**

Sharks with lasers that blast through the ocean! 
Yeah! Could it work though?

I am looking for some weapons to place on my sharks with fixed weapons on their heads. How feasible is it to mount laser weapons on their heads?

Comment: The question is good, the wording needs to change to fit the site better. For example, "I am looking for some weapons to place on my frigging sharks with friggin weapons on their heads. How feasible is it to mount laserweapons on their heads? Bonus: in case of a lack of sharks, bad tempered seabarse will be weaponized".

Comment: You will get downvotes for questions which are unclear, poorly researched and unuseful. Take a look at the [help] and take the [tour] to understand what we expect from a good question.

Comment: I think that my edit clarified the question. Can the [on hold] status now be removed @L.Dutch ?

Comment: @LMD, I rejected the proposed edit. Such drastic changes are better left to the OP.

Comment: What "blast through the ocean"? The shark or the laser?

Comment: Is there a question to be answered here?

Comment: This site is dedicated to helping people develop and consistently use the rules and systems of their own fictional world. You don't seem to be doing that. Worse, [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110), meaning you need to ask about a problem you need solved such that a best answer can be selected.  You've not provided the context to permit that.  Are you trying to develop a world (good, Q needs improvement)? or is this just a silly "off the top of my head" question meant to start a discussion (bad...)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lasers are a poor choice of weapon underwater; they're attenuated far too strongly... at best, they've got a thousand times less useful range than their in-air equivalents.

Compare this:

[image: EM attenuation in water]

with this:

[image: EM attenuation in air]

Longer attenuation lengths are better, as they show that a particular frequency is better at penetrating that particular medium. There's a little peak at the blue-green point in the spectrum, which people are using for udnerwater optical communication, but no-one seriously expects to do anything more dangerous than transmit harsh language (or detonation codes) over it.

So, best case, your underwater laser isn't any more useful than a [torpedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpedo) or [rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitating_torpedo) or [underwater gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_firearm), to be honest.

Comment: [Answer well asked question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), please.

Comment: @L.Dutch those reversal badges don't award themselves ;-)

Comment: Sharks might use such lasers to kill seals as they breach. Water opacity would not be a hurdle.

Comment: @Renan it is less convenient and effective than using the enormous mouthful of killing spikes they already have, especially given that they don't kill airborne or beached seals. Now, killerwhales spyhopping to find seals, on the other hand...

Comment: @StarfishPrime  technically they do, once you hit the right combination of triggers